# How to set fixed maximum x axis on Highchart type datetime

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How to set fixed maximum x axes on Highchart type datetime,

[full width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNtub.png)
[mini width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOCyR.png)

every time I make a width change in the browser the number of x axes will adjust, can I make the number of x axes fixed?

use tickAmount still not working

Thanks

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'DateTime chart',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime', 
        tickAmount : 4
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [
            [1412199680000, 7.0],
            [1412199980000, 6.9],
            [1412200580000, 9.5],
            [1412200880000, 14.5],
            [1412201180000, 18.4],
            [1412201480000, 21.5],
            [1412201780000, 25.2],
            [1412202080000, 26.5],
            [1412202380000, 23.3],
            [1412202680000, 18.3],
            [1412202980000, 13.9],
            [1412203280000, 9.6]
        ]
    }]
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/ulhas87/vo81poeh/

Comment: To control ticks on axis you can use one of the available API options, like tickPositioner, tickPositions, tickInterval, tickPixelInterval. tickPositioner is the most flexible. You could use default positions for other time range like month or week, and custom positions for day range.
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickPositioner